# UI loading weirdly upon adding import BrowserAnimation module in app.module.ts

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-material2

I am new to angular 4 and trying to use angular material version 2.0.0-beta.12 with angular 4 for creating a module. However, angular material works requires angular cdk and angular animation to be installed along with angular material module.

I have included below statement in the app.module.ts
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

However, upon adding above statement screen behaves weird. Upon click of back button with in the application, it appends the controls preset in the previous page with the existing page.

Not sure how.
Please guide.

Comment: You are new to Angular but are using versions from several years ago? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Is there any reason to use angular 4 in 2019? Also, material 2.0.0-beta.12 doesn't seems to be the cleverest choice with angular 4. Can't you update?

Comment: This is an ongoing project using angular 4...and i m trying to implement modal window into it so was using angular material with it

Comment: Is angular material not appropriate to use for creating modal windows within angular 4??

Comment: @Pall : what they mean is angular4 is older than 2 years, if you start a new project I'm afraid there's no good reason not to upgrade to a recent version (7 or even 8). As stated in [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/releases#support-policy-and-schedule), angular4 is no longer updated/supported.

Comment: Are you asking me to upgrade my application to latest version of angular? Can upgrading my angular version within the project affect my application ideally?